# Reseting the bone roll value to 0

Tags: rigging, bones

I have an armature and i have aligned some of the bones to specific axes and now these bones have a roll value different from zero. I know that is supposed to happen but is there a way to reset to roll values to 0 as if you would do when applying the scale or rotation of an object? I know there was the option "clear bone roll" (shortcut ctrl-n ) in older versions but it seems that the developers removed it for some reason.

Comment: This is indeed a limitation in Blender, committed clear-roll operator: http://developer.blender.org/rB2177f645855c242399f3d3324f4d8e0357c3601c

Comment: @ideasman42 It looks that that commit is from today, so it's not in master yet. Although, OP actually wants something like Applying transformations.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible and, in my opinion, unnecessary. The orientation of the bone in the Edit Mode is not important at all, that transformations will count as cleared in Pose Mode. Why do you want to be cleared in Edit Mode?

Comment: @AntonioBuch the roll of the bone defines the axis orientation, when rotating using the local bone axis the roll changes which way the bone rotates.

Comment: @sambler Yes, but any orientation could be good depending on your needs. Until the Alt R feature is implemented, use the Ctrl N operator. If you could post an image of what you got and what you want, it could be good to help you up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find which version of Blender had the option to clear when calculating roll, however this seems like it is something Blender should be able to do.

Added http://developer.blender.org/rB2177f645855c242399f3d3324f4d8e0357c3601c

Access from the armature roll menu, or by pressing Alt-R.

Comment: Being added during the release cycle I don't expect this to be included with the 2.77 release. If anyone wants to use this feature before this change is included in a release you can find an [addon here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/clear_bone_roll.py) to perform the same action.

Comment: ALT+R causes the bones to rotate -- this is different from applying the roll.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.81a to enter the *Recalculate Roll* menu choose the rolled bone and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: Recalculate Roll causes the bones to be rotated -- it is different from applying the roll. -- And it certainly does not set the roll to 0 for any of the bones. -- As for CTRL + N, that's strange, for me it just gives me a new file prompt. -- I don't think that hotkey is universal.

Comment: The hotkey is Shift-N I believe.

Comment: The hotkey is Shift-N I believe.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 3.0 to *Recalculate Roll* is with the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

[image: sub-menu]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for! :-)